# Count coloured cells in each column and return count

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to find an easier way to return the amount of coloured cells per column. My code so far:

```
Sub errors()

Dim Sheet1 As String
Dim mycell As Range
Dim datecol As Long
Dim col As Long

Sheet1 = "different"    

For Each mycell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSheet1).Range("B:B")
    If mycell.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
        datecol = datecol + 1
End If
Next mycell

Debug.Print datecol

End Sub
```

If I have 40 columns this is pretty tedious and slow, is  there a better way to do this (pretty new in learning vba) hence I am repeating several For each loops and specifying the column. I need help improving the code or a new method for returning the amount of coloured cells per column.

Comment: why not loop the for each loop in another that loops through all the columns you need?

Comment: Do you *really* need to check each of the (typically) 1048576 cells in the column? Or -- just the cells that are actually used? Also -- if the cell color is due to conditional formatting -- why not directly count the cells that satisfy the condition?

Comment: @JohnColeman I am just looking to count the coloured cells in the used rows of data. I am trying to break down a summary per column header so i can fix any errors quickly.

Comment: @Tony something like Range(Cells(1,2),Cells(rows.Count,2).End(xlUp)) is a standard trick to get the range at the top of a column that contains all of the cells which actually have values. Note that the 2 can be replaced by a variable which steps through a range of columns in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way is fine, but it can be refined -

```
Sub test()
Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim cntclr As Integer
cntclr = 0
For i = 1 To lastrow
    If Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = vbRed Then
        cntclr = cntclr + 1
    End If
Next
MsgBox (cntclr)
End Sub
```

If you want to do it for each column, this will do it and print the results, just change the range where the array populates

```
Sub test()
Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim lastcol As Integer
lastcol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Dim arr() As String
ReDim arr(1 To lastcol, 1)
Dim cntClr As Integer
Dim strCol As String
Dim strCnt As String

For j = 1 To lastcol

    cntClr = 0
    For i = 1 To lastrow
    If Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = vbRed Then
        cntClr = cntClr + 1
    End If
    Next
    strCol = "Col " & Chr(64 + j)
    strCnt = Str(cntClr)
    arr(j, 0) = strCol
    arr(j, 1) = cntClr

Next
Range("D1:E" & lastcol) = arr()
End Sub
```

Comment: your second solution is great however when i adjust the range and remove the "Col " & Chr(64 + j)" it produces the list of numbers and then a list of "n/a" after

Comment: Why remove the col & char? It's the string for the array that takes the column number and converts it to a letter. If you're not starting at A, just change the 64 to a larger number. Or start J at the correct column.

Comment: i already have the list of columns to associate to the numbers in the array, therefore i do not need to display "Col A" etc. However when I change Range("D1:E" & lastcol) = arr()  to D10 it produces a list of "n/a" after  the array

Comment: You'll need to dimension the array to a single (vertical) array and print only the count. You could make it an integer array instead of string.

Comment: If you have a specific range where you want to print the counts, you don't need the array at all - you can just print directly there after the count loop. If you need help with that, just let me know where the output range is and what columns you actually need to help, but I'm sure you can probably figure that part out no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Sub errors()

    Dim Sheet1 As String
    Dim mycell As Range
    Dim datecol As Long
    Dim col As Long

    Sheet1 = "different"

    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastrow As Long
    Dim myrng as Range
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet1)
    lastrow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ' If you think you may have colored cells with no data
    ' Set myrng = ws.UsedRange.Rows
    ' lastrow = myrng(myrng.Count).Row

    Set myrng = ws.Range("B1:B" & lastrow)
    For Each mycell In myrng
        If mycell.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
            datecol = datecol + 1
        End If
    Next mycell

    Debug.Print datecol

End Sub
```